# How to grab specific data from Firebase using Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So currently I have an Android based project that is connected to the Realtime Database by Google's firebase. Within the database I have multiple children that each have a Coordinate and a Title. The goal is to extract each of these children's data and add them as markers in a google map.

[Example of data in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usjLS.png)

My current problem is that I cannot figure out a way to just grab the "Coord" and "Title" data from my dataSnapshot, and put them into a array list to then add as markers to the map. So far here is my code.

```
database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

               for (ds in dataSnapshot.children){
                    Log.d("TAG","Check the DS: " + ds)
                    val coordData = ds.child("Markers").getValue()
                    Log.d("TAG", "Check the Data: " + coordData)
                }


                fireMarkers.add(dataSnapshot.getValue())

                for (location in fireMarkers)
                {
                    Log.d("DATA", "Check location: " + location)
                    val markerValue = location.toString()

                    val result = markerValue.replace("[^\bCoord=(-|)[0-9]*,\\s(-|)[0-9]*]".toRegex(), "")

                    Log.d("TAG", "Check location RESULT are: " + result)
                    val checkResult = result.split(",").toTypedArray()
                    Log.d("TAG", "Check location RESULT SPLIT are: " + checkResult)
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                //print error.message
                Log.e("TAG", "Snap didn't work " + error)
            }
        })
```

I still haven't figured out how to grab those specific tags from the database and populate them into the fireMarkers array. I would want to just directed grab that data from Firebase, however I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this line `Log.d("TAG", "Check the Data: " + coordData)` print in the logcat?

Comment: 2020-03-04 10:04:10.069 30945-30945/com.geo.tag D/TAG: Check the Data: {Coord=44, -110, Title=BYUI}

2020-03-04 10:04:10.071 30945-30945/com.geo.tag D/TAG: 


Check the Data: {Coord=43.8231, -111.7924, Title=Rexburg Marker}

Comment: How is `database` defined?